# Shell script : Dividing the xml messages in single string into array based on start and end tags in solaris

Tags: xml, shell

I trying to divide the given string into array based on tag

```
start-tag <BookMsg> end-tag </BookMsg>
string="<BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>AAAA</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg><BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>BBBB</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg><BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>CCC</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg>"
```

Note that its long string with no new line.

Expected Result:

```
MessageARRAY[0]=  <BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>AAAA</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg>

MessageARRAY[1]= <BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>BBBB</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg>

MessageARRAY[2]= <BookMsg><Book><Chapter><Line>CCCC</Line></Chapter></Book></BookMsg>
```

I tried using below approach:

```
echo $string > book.xml
IFS=$'\n'
MessageARRAY=($(grep -A 3 '<bookMsg>' ~/book.xml | awk '{printf "%s",$0} $0~"</bookMsg>" {print}'))
```

Unfortunately, -A option is not available with grep in solaris.

Can any one please guide me on achieving the results on Solaris 10?